# Error (2.17): PLS-00201: The identifier 'DAYS_INTERVAL_TABLE' must be declared

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, functions, plsql, plsql-developer

I recently installed an `Oracle 12c` in `Oracle Linux 7.6`, it was previously in `Windows`.  In the first database restored, some functions are with compilation errors.

The query below informs you that there is a syntax error on `line 2`, but I can not figure out where the problem is.

**Error:** `Error (2.17): PLS-00201: The identifier 'DAYS_INTERVAL_TABLE' must be declared`

**Query:**

```
create or replace FUNCTION funRetornaDias (p_inicio date, p_termino date)
         RETURN DAYS_INTERVAL_TABLE PIPELINED IS

    v_date date;
    out_rec DAYS_INTERVAL := DAYS_INTERVAL(NULL,NULL);
    v_ref date;

BEGIN

    if p_inicio > p_termino then
        v_ref := p_inicio;
        v_date := p_termino;
    else
        v_ref := p_termino;
        v_date := p_inicio;
    end if; 

    while cast(to_char(v_date, 'YYYYMMDD') as number) <= cast(to_char(v_ref, 'YYYYMMDD') as number) loop
    begin

        out_rec.date_ := v_date;
        out_rec.day_of_week := datepart('DW', v_date);

        PIPE ROW(out_rec);
        v_date := v_date + interval '1' day;

    end;
    end loop;

    RETURN;

END;
```

Comment: The problem is exactly what the error message tells. `DAYS_INTERVAL_TABLE` is a custom type, but it was not created.

Comment: If you want to compare a `DATE` to `DATE`, then you should change `cast(to_char( var, 'YYYYMMDD') as number)` to `trunc( var )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the `impdb` log and saw that this object was not imported due to an `OID` conflict.

At the beginning of the log I found this message.

```
ORA-39083: Object type TYPE:"VERZANI"."DAYS_INTERVAL" failed to create with error:
ORA-02304: invalid object identifier literal

    Failing sql is:
    CREATE EDITIONABLE TYPE "VERZANI"."DAYS_INTERVAL"   OID 'C01480BB3D223837E0430100007FED58' AS OBJECT
           (DATE_           DATE,
            DAY_OF_WEEK     number(1,0));
    ORA-39083: Object type TYPE:"VERZANI"."DAYS_INTERVAL_TABLE" failed to create with error:
    ORA-02304: invalid object identifier literal

    Failing sql is:
    CREATE EDITIONABLE TYPE "VERZANI"."DAYS_INTERVAL_TABLE"   OID 'C01480BB3D273837E0430100007FED58' AS TABLE OF DAYS_INTERVAL;
```

So I dropped the schema and rerun the `impdp` again with the parameter `TRANSFORM=oid:n`. Now the database went up without any problems.

Comment: you should accept your answer as answer, otherwise your post will be regularly "bumped to the homepage" as unanswerded